# How should I drain a capacitor in a rectifier circuit?

Tags: resistors, transformer, discharge, smoothing-capacitor

I am trying to learn how to drain a capacitor after disconnecting power from a rectifier circuit.
Specifically what I have is a step down transformer from an old wall wart charger that I have modified. Orginally it stepped 120VAC down to about 11.5VAC. I have modified it by removing a few turns from its primary coil resulting in an output of about 14VAC. I then ran it through a full bridge rectifier and added 2 capacitors in parallel (caps are each rated 25v 2200uf). When I read the DC voltage of the output wires I get roughly 21.5VDC. 
So in instances when I have no load attached when disconnecting power, how do I ensure the caps drain? My original idea is to add a high value resistor in parallel right after the capacitors. I have a 35k ohm 1/4watt resistor laying around. Would that be adequate for quickly draining the caps without causing a noticeable power loss?
Are there other simple methods that I may be unaware of?
Realistically, the most this power supply will be used for is to power low power test circuits through a step down module.

Note: This is not for any particular purpose or anything of importance. I am simply an at-home hobbyist who is experimenting and tinkering for the sole purpose of learning. I find trying to understand how different circuits work and trying to replicate or alter them, to be extremely intriguing. So feel free to throw out different ideas or point out any flaws in my design, because I am open to any knowledge you can share.[image: Picture of Setup]

Comment: What do you mean by "a high value resistor in parallel right after the capacitors"? Parallel sounds fine, but "right after" implies series, so that doesn't really add up in my mind. Could you draw a schematic? That would make it much easier to discuss your circuit.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are on the right track, and you want a [bleeder resistor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bleeder_resistor). The discharge time is approximated by 5CR which in your case is rather long : 4400u x 35k x 5 = 770s. There is a trade off here between fast enough discharge and power dissipation. I would suggest about 1k/1W which gives 22s, reasonable, and power dissipation of somewhere less than 0.5W, which is fine for your experiment I think.

Comment: A good rule of thumb is to keep 5RC to a maximum of 30s when you don't have a specific reason for making it longer so, due to the exponential discharge curve, most of your voltage drop will have occurred by 1 or 2RC.